# Where to find SoftwareSerial.h library for arduino?

Tags: compilation, arduino

I include `SoftwareSerial.h` in my code. But when I compile the code, following error occurs:

```
GPS_TEST_3.ino:2:28: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Error compiling
```

Any idea on this? Where the header file is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install the arduino compiler? This is a standard library that is part of the install.

You could try looking in your /libraries subfolder of the main arduino folder. the file should be in there. Is it?

Comment: But there is another problem. I am using Arduino Due  to check the code this error display ...........

WARNING: library SoftwareSerial claims to run on [avr] architecture(s) and may be incompatible with your current board which runs on [sam] architecture(s).

C:\Users\COMMANDER\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:45:30: fatal error: util/delay_basic.h: No such file or directory
 #include <util/delay_basic.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.

Comment: Sounds like the library is incompatible with your mc. Which microcontroller or arduino board are you using? Also what version of the arduino IDE do you have? Have you compiled any other programs before on the same setup?

Answer (score 3):

In my desktop its at 
Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial\src
while other libraries like sdcard eeprom reside at
Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries

Comment: On my computer it is also at that location, but how do I let the library (in my case the Airgradient library) search that path so that it actually finds the `SoftwareSerial.h`? I installed the Arduino IDE via the official website of Arduino.